# Problems accessing same SESSION variables from different files

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, session

I'm developing a site using Wordpress.

My permalink structure is set to show post/page name. So accessing a page called *store* will look like this: `www.mysite.com/store/?some=arguments`

In all my WP templates, I'm able to output all my SESSION variables using `print_r($_SESSION);`

Doing the same from a file called from `jQuery.ajax` only outputs some of the SESSION varaibles.

I've used the following code to see if the cookie path is same for both files, and they are:

```
$sessCookie = ini_get('session.cookie_path'); 
echo 'session.cookie_path: '.$sessCookie;
```

I also have this code in my files to make sure session is started:

```
if (!session_id())
  session_start();
```

Why am I not able to output the same session variables from a WP template and a php file called from `jQuery.ajax`?

**UPDATE**

`jQuery.ajax` calls `jquery.php` file. At the top of this file, it has the following code:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php');
```

This code fires `functions.php`. In this file I have the following code:

```
function session_manager() {
  if (!session_id())
        session_start();

  // Get variables in query string
  $_SESSION['action'] = (isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '');
  $user_geo_data = get_geoip_record();     
  $_SESSION['user_geo_location'] = get_object_vars($user_geo_data);
}
```

When `functions.php` is fired from `jquery.php`, it seems that `session_id()` returns false, thus I create a new session.

Is there a way to keep using the same session?

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that WP config kills all GLOBAL variables when initialized.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-blog-headerphp-killing-sessions

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress can use its own session handler, and overrides the default session handler to do so. So in essence you've got two different sessions, even though they share the same ID. The cookie path is merely how the client-side cookie operates. What you need to check is [`session_save_path()`](http://php.net/session_save_path), and check if WP is running sessions through the database instead of the default file handler.

Comment: The save path is same for both (`I:/Development/wamp/tmp`). I also tested `session_id()`, and they are not the same.

Comment: Ok, if the session IDs are different, then there's two separate sessions in play. Check `session_name()` in both - you'll probably find you've got 2 session cookies floating back and forth. the names and ids have to be the same before you can share the session between the two systems.

Comment: I've tested that and they are both using the default value: `PHPSESSID`.

Comment: Very odd then. I can't see how a single browser would send two different values for the same cookie, when everything else is identical. It'd be possible if the two cookies had different cookie paths (but you say both are `/`), or one was secure-only and the other wasn't.

Comment: I deleted all session cookies in my `/tmp/` folder and monitored the content of that dir. One session is created when browsing normal pages, and a new session is created when I call my `uploadify.php`. The content of these two files are not the same (opened in Notepad).

Comment: uploadify uses flash... it's probably not picking up on your parent session, so it creates a new one.

Comment: see my update. I think I know why a new session is being created.

Answer (score 0):

The reason two sessions are fired up is because the first one is browser-based (through a cookie) and the second one, with `Ajax`, is essentially server-side and doesn't have access to the session cookie.

The session cookie is where the session ID is stored and is used to identify an existing session. A server-side `Ajax` script doesn't have access to the browser's cookies, thus fires up a new session.

It can be worse if the main script uses an alternate session "*save handler*" than the `Ajax` script, resulting in two separate sessions, stored in two different places.